# Finding next prime number logic error

Tags: logic, output, primes

I have a function to determine if a given number is prime. I have been attempting to write a function to find the next prime number after the given number. The problem is that it only works on certain numbers.

I pretty much just gave it my best guess so if its poorly written that would be why.

```
# include <stdio.h>

int next(int);
int is_prime(int);

int main()
{
        int num;
        printf("Enter a number\n");
        scanf("%d", &num);

printf("next prime is %d\n",  next(num));

return 0;
```

This next part is to check if its prime

```
is_prime(int n)
{
        int i, test=0;

        for (i=2; i<=n/2; i++)
        {
                if(n%i==0)
                {
                        test++;
                        break;
                }
        }
        if (test==0)
                return 1;
         else
                return 0;
}
```

now the function to check for the next prime number

```
int next(int x)
{
        int y, i;

        for(i=x+1; i>0;  i++)
        {
                if(is_prime(i)==1)
                                return i;
                                break;
        }
}
```

I don't know if it matters but some samples that worked where 6, 10 and 12
but 7, 8, 13, and 14 did not work.

Comment: replace `for (i=2; i<=n/2; i++)` with `for (i=2; i*i<=n; i++)` inside `is_prime(int n)`.

Comment: Why with eazars advice I removed the break in `int next(int x)` and it works.

Comment: yes, and with my change it will work faster. :) I didn't mean it *instead* of the answer, sorry I wasn't clear about it. :)

Comment: @Bradg89, @Will Ness is right, basically he is using an old mathematical trick that states that you only need to test for divisors from 2 up to the square root of n, instead of all the way up to n/2. @Will Ness simply expressed this in another way by squaring `n^1/2` and then squaring `i` to re-state the equality from `i </ n^1/2` to `i^2 </ n^1/2`. I assure you, @Will Ness, means no harm, he is just suggesting to make your algorith faster by exponential magnitudes. It scales very well at larger numbers. Try it!

Comment: sorry, that inequality should of course read `i^2 </ n`, not `i^2 </ n^1/2`. Typo.

Comment: @eazar001 it's important to use `<=`, not `<`, there.  :) i never saw such a notation, `</`, before. :)

Comment: @Will Ness, haha, got caught thinking in traditional math notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem is the `break` statement, remove it.**

```
int next(int x)
{
    int y, i;

    for(i=x+1; i>0;  i++)
    {
        if(is_prime(i)==1)
            return i;
            break;       //delete this line
    } 
}
```

What is happening is that, after every first test, you are **immediately** breaking out of the loop. Which is why numbers like 6, 10, and 12 are working. That is because the next number immediately after is a prime number. For every other case where the next **immediate** number is not prime, this won't work; it will break if a prime isn't reached. If you want to execute more than one statement in an if-branch, you must wrap them in `{}` braces.

**This is the correct form for multiple statements in an if-branch:**

```
if(is_prime(i)==1)
{
    return i;
    break;  
}
```

Comment: np, please read the update, it will help you with similar problems.